# Validate key of Request in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

How I can Validate Key of Request instead of Value of Key in laravel validation

For Example:

I have JSON Data like this

```
{
    "phone":{
        "4969929292":"214"
    },
    "email":{
        "example@gmail.com":"212"
    }
}
```

*How I can validate 4969929292(It is key ) this number* and 
*How I can validate 214 (This is value)*.

Can any help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `key()` function: Example below:

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "phone":{
        "4969929292":"214"
    },
    "email":{
        "example@gmail.com":"212"
    }
}';


$arr = json_decode($json, true);

$key = key($arr['phone']);
$value = $arr['phone'][$key];
```